# Как можно добавить crash файлы в xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Всем привет, заливаю в itunes приложение через ci, в дженкинсе уже собирается ipa и заливается itunes, приложение реджектнули, так как оно у них упало, прислали логи с крэшами, я не могу их теперь совместить с приложением, так как после отправки в айтюнс билдил другие ветки, и нету файла dSYM, собирал архив и пытался сопоставить с логами но ничего не получается. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, то как решали? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да вряд ли получится. можно попробовать сделать rebuild того билда в дженкинсе, который загружали. может прокатит.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да я уже наверное весь инет перерыл и что самое интересное через атос все таки удалось понять, что в логах примерно, но так и не понятно где оно упало, так как приложение падало в системных процессах, и крэшилось оно у них при переходе на любой экран, хотя как я уже только не тестировал у меня ни удалось уронить его. Может просто перезалить по-новой?

Comment: заливайте, тогда сразу dsym сохрание где нить. и помните, что они 22го идут на каникулы до 28го. торопитесь :)